# Passing an object to phonegap plugin instead of a string

Tags: javascript, cordova, phonegap-plugins

I have created a simple plugin for phonegap but i want to pass a object as a parameter instead of string , below is my code structure...

```
BackGroundService.java  

public class BackGroundService extends Plugin {
   public PluginResult execute(String arg0, JSONArray args, String arg2) {  //How can i pass object instead or String       
   }
}

worker.js
var worker = function(name, win, fail) {   
  PhoneGap.exec(win, win, "BackGroundService", "worker", [name]);
}

PhoneGap.addConstructor(function() {
  navigator.app.addService('BackGroundService','com.service.app.BackGroundService');

})
```

Calling from html

```
worker("football", win);   //Pass object instead of football        

var win = function(d) {
     alert("success");      
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Unpack the object into an array of strings?

Let's say you are passing an Object called "Sport" with the following properties:

.name: "Football"
.ball: "round"
.periods: 2
.periodTiming: 45

You could unpack this object into ["Football", "round", 2, 45], and, modify your Java code to pick up each parameter:

```
    String name = args.getString(0);
    String ball = args.getString(1);
    int periods = args.getInt(2);
    int timing = args.getInt(3);
```

HTH